# SOLR: filter querying a multivalue field

Tags: solr, solrj

I have the following multivalue field whereby i'm interested in the first bit before the colon. ie 4 and 1

```
<document>
    <bla>1</bla>
    <arr name="foobar_mv_s">
       <str>4:999</str>
       <str>1:10000</str>
    </arr>
</document>
 <document>
    <bla>2</bla>
    <arr name="foobar_mv_s">
       <str>5:123</str>
       <str>3:2222</str>
    </arr>
</document>
```

Example I'd like to be able to create a filter query that basically returns document 1 as there is a 4 within the multivalue field.

e.g. something like the following filter query
   foobar_mv_s: (4:*)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type for `foobar_mv_s`?

Comment: If `foobar_mv_s` is a string, you can do a regex search: `foobar_mv_s:/.*4:.*/`

Comment: A wildcard search should also work, if you escape the colon: foobar_mv_s:4\:*